# Error when running poisson regression with a binary outcome

Tags: r, binary, glm, poisson

I am trying to run a poisson regression to predict a **common** binary outcome.

This is my first attempt at using `dput` - if I have used it inappropriately, please let me know so I can correct it.

**Example data:**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:30, sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"
), class = "factor"), migStat = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Australian-born", 
"Migrant"), class = "factor"), mhAreaBi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Metropolitan", 
"Regional"), class = "factor"), empStatBi = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Student / employed", 
"Unemployed"), class = "factor"), pensBenBi = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No benefit", 
"In receipt of pension benefit"), class = "factor"), maritStatBi = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Married (including de facto)", 
"Not married"), class = "factor"), cto = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "sex", "migStat", 
"mhAreaBi", "empStatBi", "pensBenBi", "maritStatBi", "cto"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

When running the regression using `glm` in R, I receive an error:

```
fit <- glm(cto ~ sex + migStat + mhAreaBi + empStatBi + pensBenBi + maritStatBi, df, family = poisson)

Error in if (any(y < 0)) stop("negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(y, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

The same error has been explained briefly [in this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/GLM-HELP-NEEDED-td4728529.html):

> Because the "<" operator is not defined for factors the result that is
>   passed to `if` is of length 0. Setting the factor variable on the RHS
>   and using the integer values on hte LHS succeeds.

The error does not appear when I convert the outcome to an integer; however, this:

1. seems to defeat the purpose of predicting a binary outcome (unless a numeric variable with range 0-1 is treated the same as a factor variable with two levels); and
2. does not seem necessary (at least according to this [post](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5752_fc41dca85dd24539bc99868697de83d0.html), which uses `geeglm` from `geepack` to predict a binary outcome [unfortunately, I receive the same error when I adapt the code to my own dataset])

**Questions:**

Could I receive further explanation of the error?

If I convert my outcome to an integer with range 0-1, will `glm` treat it the same as a binary variable? If not, is there an approach better suited to running a regression for a common binary outcome?

Comment: `as.numeric(df$cto == "Yes")` will give you 0's and 1's that will work well in `glm`. But normally you use logistic regression for binary outcomes like this, and Poisson regression for count or rate variables, where the outcome can take any integer values > 0. Are you sure Poisson is a good choice for your analysis?

Comment: @Marius I appreciate the tip! Going through university, I have been taught that logistic regression is used for binary outcomes and poisson regression is used for count data. More recently, a statistician at my university informed me that logistic regression is appropriate for use when binary outcomes are rare, but that it runs into trouble when outcomes are common. In those instances, it is supposedly better to use poisson regression. Here is a thread on CV - [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18595/poisson-regression-to-estimate-relative-risk-for-binary-outcomes)

Comment: Regarding your point 1 above, the statement after "unless" is correct -- converting to a 0,1 binary variable (i.e. dummy variable) is exactly what you want to do. In your linked `geeglm` example, the outcome is coded as `TRUE` and `FALSE` -- i.e., `1` and `0`--which is why they did not convert in that post, but were able to carry out the regression.

Comment: Just to be clear - for _any_ given 0/1 variable, they will be equivalent if coded as a factor or numeric? Therefore, R will distinguish reliably between two numeric variables coded 0/1 (binary) and 0, 1, 2,...(count)?

Comment: When factor is being coerced to numeric, you have to be wary of the order in which is done. Compare `levels(factor(letters[1:3]))` and `levels(factor(letters[1:3], levels = c("c", "a", "b")))` and coerce them to numeric.

Comment: OK, just wanted to check re the logistic/poisson thing, but as you say there are valid reasons to use Poisson. You have to be very careful when using factors in R and check ordering of levels etc. before using them, that's why I like using `as.numeric(df$cto == "Yes")` which explicitly shows what a success/1 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option here is:

```
df$cto_binary <- as.numeric(df$cto == "Yes")
fit <- glm(cto_binary ~ sex + migStat + mhAreaBi + empStatBi + pensBenBi + maritStatBi, 
           df, family = poisson)
```

As this way you explicitly show in your code what will be a 1/success in your binary outcome and don't get tripped up by things like the ordering of factor levels. Note that in R `as.numeric(c(FALSE, TRUE))` gives `c(0, 1)`, so you always know what you're going to get from a logical comparison.